# Logging out and in resets modifier keys to defaults

Tags: keyboard

1. Open Keyboard Preferences
2. Set modifier keys (I like to reverse option and command)
3. Log out
4. Log in
5. Modifier keys have been reset to defaults

I just upgraded from 10.7.5 to 10.8.2, might be related.

Every time I open Keyboard Preferences, I see the following in my console:

> System Preferences[570]: [BluetoothHIDDevice][initWithHIDDevice] Unable to get Object ID from IORegistry

.. so that might be related.

Comment: Does it happen with other user?

Comment: @Thecafremo yes.  I tried creating a new user and it happens with them as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. Uninstalled Intellitype
2. Restarted in safe mode (hold shift)
3. Use Disk Utility to Repair Permissions
4. Restart

Seems to have fixed the problem.  Perhaps some config file wasn't writable?  Who knows ..